# How to Loop an function event by class?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to loop an function by click on class. the code look like this.

**Class Ways**

***HTML***

```
<button class="btn">B</button>
<button class="btn">I</button>
<div id="ctn"></div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
<script>
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var ctn = document.getElementById('ctn');
ctn.contentEditable = true;

for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
var a = ["'bold'","'italic'"];
btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
document.execCommand(a[i],false,null);
}, false);}

</script>
```

When it click it doesn't happen anthing. look below the manual by using ID.

**ID Ways**

***HTML***

```
<button id="bold">B</button>
<button id="italic">I</button>
<div id="ctn"></div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
    var bold = document.getElementById('bold');
    var italic = document.getElementById('italic');

    bold.addEventListener('click', function(){document.execCommand('bold',false,null);}, false);
italic.addEventListener('click', function(){document.execCommand('italic',false,null);}, false);
```

with ID ways is it work. but Class doesn't work. how to loop function by class?

nb: answer it on JavaScript not JQuery. Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Why are your strings double quoted?  `"'bold'"`.

Comment: #James its a value for first argument of addEventListener. ex. addEventListener('bold',function(){},false);

Comment: `addEventListener("bold"` makes no sense.  Bold isn't an event.  And even if it was, there's no reason to have two sets of quotes.

Comment: #James oops sory, its for first argument of execCommand('bold',false,nul);

Comment: Still shouldn't be double quoted.

Comment: The problem is the dupe quesiton and the fact you double quoted the strings. The deleted answer just missed that problem.

Comment: #James Look my code. var a =["'bold'","'italic'"];. to create array to string u need double quotes or single quotes but cause i need a result that display string nested in single. so i put that's ways. viola the result 'bold' and 'italic' for first argument execCommand function

Comment: @DavidSlavalia that is WRONG...you do NOT need the quotes! You are doing this `document.execCommand("'bold'",false,null);` Does your hardcoded string look like that?

Comment: If someone here has enough votes to undelete @tymeJV's answer, I edited it to fix the quote issue.

Comment: #James so u say execCommand is not need single quote? just execCommand(bold,false,null);? are u sure what you say? i tried document.write(a[0]); it return 'bold' not "'bold'".

Comment: @DavidSlavalia You need to learn about strings.

Comment: You know that one line works, change it to a variable `var x = "bold"; bold.addEventListener('click', function(){document.execCommand(x,false,null);}, false);`

Comment: #epascarello what do you means the last comment? i don't get it. your code it same as mine. can you fix how to loop using by class? like as editor say. its binding problem, i think. i have see the answer but the example is too hardcore. so i need answer that by my code.

Comment: The answer below is correct. And my comment above has different code. I am showing you the fact that the quotes are "WRONG".

Comment: #epascarello my connection is lag. so it get delay. Thank you ma bro :). i think you're right.

Comment: #epascarello sory to disquise. as i look function binding.
for()[
(function)(i);}

what is use for the last (i) on for bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a closure to bind elements in a loop like that:

```
for(i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
    (function(i) {  //closure inside so i is correct. 
        var a = ["bold","italic"]; //removed quotes
        btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.execCommand(a[i],false,null);
        }, false)
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: I just replace your code ma bro. but it doesn't work. i think you know  what i do now. i want to make WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: With the change I made to `var a = ....` this code should work.

Comment: Its work :) so the problem is on array. but i still dont get it binding ways. i need to get attention too much on this. its hardcore alorigthm. thank you for you hard time :)

Comment: The OP is already using a closure. The solution is to call a function to create a new scope.

Comment: sory to disquise. as i look function binding. `for(){ (function)(i);}` what is use for the last `(i`) on for bracket?

Comment: It's the parameter being passed in